# Code required to trigger optional selected link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I've got the following code which correctly selects an option in a list of option links using information provided by the previous url, but although the correct link is selected visually when the code runs, the results appear as if the link was not actively selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.optionLink:contains('"+ (document.referrer.split('/').pop()) +"')").click();
});
```

Do i need to add an execute or trigger code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the browser actually gets redirected to the link's target?

Comment: its a link as part of a multi-link search list of a dbase so there is no page redirection

Comment: Is it possible that there is more than one selected link? Can you link to a live page or recreate this?

Comment: sure no prob: http://www.legalcounseldirect.com/Lawyersearch, to see what i mean you need to come onto the first link through a trigger url, eg http://www.legalcounseldirect.com/France   thanks

Comment: Perhaps not all of the listeners were attached. You could try and set a timeout to execute the function some 50ms or so after page load.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how i could write that code pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant code is problematic in a few ways:

First, the exception handling code (try/catch) is outside of the function, which is no a great idea.

Second, it is scanning all of the links in the page for an expression which might be empty (in which case, hundreds of links may be triggered).

Last but not least, the referrer may not contain the exact phrase as the links. For example, `England & Wales` is related to `http://www.legalcounseldirect.com/England&Wales` (which shows a `Resource not found` error, but this is another matter). I would consider dynamically generating a link to the search page with a query string or a fragment, so that this hack would be unnecessary.

That said, a solution that might do the trick most of the time could be:

either:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    setTimeout(function(){
        try{
            var lastSegment = document.referrer.split('/').pop();
            if(lastSegment != "") {
                var matches = $("#idFilterColumns a.optionLink:contains('"+ lastSegment  +"')");
                if(matches.length === 1) {
                    matches.click();
                }
            }
        }catch(e){} 
    },100);
});
```

or perhaps:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    try{
        var lastSegment = document.referrer.split('/').pop();
        if(lastSegment != "") {
            var matches = $("#idFilterColumns a.optionLink:contains('"+ lastSegment  +"')");
            if(matches.length === 1) {
                matches.click();
            }
        }
    }catch(e){}
});
```

which are triggered by 2 different events:

- The first is triggered when the document is ready, which is probably when the rest of the form functionality is being generated. Since there is no way to be sure that the script is executed after all relevant listeners are ready (and is, clearly, not), then a timeout is used in order to defer the triggering of the `click` event.
- The second code segment is triggered by a later event, the window's load. It is expected (however, not tested) that all of the event attachment is already done, so it might work without setting a timeout.

You can try one of them at a time. There is no need for both of them to be used.

Comment: Ah, its not (now) selecting any optionLink, so i cant tell if the trigger/click event is working. sorry!! I'm sure its probably a minor syntax problem? BTW thanks for your help... :-) (are smiley faces allowed?!!)

Comment: Indeed, minor syntax error. You can remove the try/catch surrounding the entire function in your page (only `<script lang...>myscript</script>`). And only sad faces are allowed.

Comment: ok its 2am here so will do that tomorrow and then let you know if it worked. thanks v much for your help :-)!!

Comment: Fantastic!!, I took out the try/catch and then just had to tweak the time out from 100 to 1500, and now works like a dream. Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. In this case, the appropriate thing to do is `accept` the answer.

Comment: This is all new to me...I think i've now accepted the answer. regards.